# Prevent updates of my app on Google Play, but still remain ability to make in app purchase

Tags: android, google-play

I have 2 versions of my app:

1. Google play version
2. Non google play version

I need 2 things:

1. If a user downloaded non-googleplay version then not update it on google play.
2. To be able to make in-app purchase in non-googleplay version.

I tried to make build-version higher for non-googleplay, but them in-app purchase becomes unavailable.

Is there way to keep fulfill both conditions?

Comment: Out of curiosity why would you want to do this? If users are buying products from Google Play, why do you care if Google Play updates the app?

Comment: @NickFortescue because version of the app will be changed to googleplay instead of nongoogleplay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think,

to do this, you need to change the package name of non google play version app.

because, package name is the major thing by which google play keep track any app. so, whenever it gets same package name app installed, it counts that in. If the package name is different, then google play won't able to track the other version. so there will be no count on that.

**Cons:** a problem may appear with app-purchases, due to changing package name.

Comment: In-app purchases won't work for sure... And changing of package name doesn't do any difference from using different build versions.